# Localhost no recibe solicitudes POST

Tags: nodejs, linux, redes, networking, archlinux

Estoy intentando realizar peticiones a una API en NodeJS de manera local en Garuda (Arch Linux), el problema está al momento de realizar una petición con un método diferente a GET a mi localhost, éste se queda esperando una respuesta pero nunca llega al servidor, cosa que no sucede al realizar un GET, cabe aclarar que no es problema de la app ya que sucede lo mismo con otros servicios, y funciona correctamente en Ubuntu y Windows.

```
curl --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
curl --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
```

**lsof -i | grep LISTEN**

```
kdeconnec   2289 rodricaceres   13u  IPv6 2973830      0t0  TCP *:xmsg (LISTEN)
node      207984 rodricaceres   19u  IPv4 3437757      0t0  TCP *:7447 (LISTEN)
node      207984 rodricaceres   20u  IPv4 3437758      0t0  TCP *:8887 (LISTEN)
node      207984 rodricaceres   21u  IPv4 3437759      0t0  TCP *:ddi-tcp-5 (LISTEN)
node      208002 rodricaceres   20u  IPv4 3354616      0t0  TCP localhost:exlm-agent (LISTEN)
node      208002 rodricaceres   21u  IPv4 3367417      0t0  TCP localhost:hbci (LISTEN)
```

**File: /etc/hosts**

```
# Host addresses
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  garuda
::1        localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1    ip6-allnodes
ff02::2    ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Si recibe un GET, tiene que recibir el POST (a nivel de protocolo), pues lo único que cambia está dentro del contenido del mensaje (cambia el _verbo HTTP_ GET por el _verbo_ POST). Todo ocurre por el mismo puerto, etc. Podrías comprobarlo con un sniffer, por ejemplo. La variación está en lo que tu aplicación haga para decidir si _invocar_ o no a tu código, luego de recibir la petición con un verbo diferente.